# Half duplex connection with a full duplex cevice

Tags: rs485, modbus, duplex

I have a sensor that I want to use with Modbus RTU and am not sure if I can use half duplex or if I need to use full duplex.

I would also like to get some suggestions how to read from it with my laptop (USB.) Not the technical part but maybe a suitable RS485 to TTL converter.

The sensor I am using is the SITRANS FC430.

This is the connector:

[image]

Comment: Modbus RTU is half duplex, so there may be some reason why they made a full duplex transceiver.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all 2 wire A/B RS485. In and Out means that you connect them in daisy chain. From the master the cable goes to In, then you connect the next device to Out.